# is it possible for me to check if I input a name and if its in the list of names in a txt file?

Tags: python, list

I tried to use the last part of the code but it doesn't work it just says false there might be some errors
and if your wondering i have a txt file with names

```
import string
string.ascii_letters 
'abcdefghijklmnOpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
import random
letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
print(letter)
file = open("names.txt")

found = [] #Result will Store
for m in file:
    if m.startswith(letter): #It will check if the input value match with from begining of the signl world
        found.append(m) # Store the value if match
for f in found:
    print("\n"+f)
print("Total Words is "+str((len(found))))

rika = input("name: ")

print(rika in found)
```

Comment: Just tested and this is the correct syntax: `print(rika) if rika in found else print("Not found")` or `print(rika if rika in found else "Not found")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an example, where **names.txt** contains:

- Thomas
- Peter
- Jens

Your Code:

```
import string, random
letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
print(letter)
with open("names.txt") as file:
    found = [] #Result will Store
    for m in file:
        if m.startswith(letter): #It will check if the input value match with from begining of the signl world
            found.append(m.strip()) # Store the value if match, remember to strip newline
    for f in found:
        print("\n"+f)
    print("Total Words are "+str(len(found)))
    if found:
        rika = input("name: ")
        print(rika if rika in found else "Not found")
```

Result:

```
J

Jens
Total Words is 1
name: Jens
Jens
```

I changed your file handling and open it using a context manager, in that way it will automatically close the file after using it. I also checked if found contain any data before asking for input.

Comment: is it working on your side it is still not working

Comment: Works fine here, what is the contents of your names.txt?

Comment: alot of names 20889 to be presice

Comment: Then dump it on pastebin or some place or edit your question and add the first 10 names from your file to give an example of how the data looks like.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cvPeM2dC

Comment: Ok, since all these start with an capital A i'll set letter equal to A in order to test it out. You are using `string.ascii_letters` which both contains small and capital letters, therefore starting the program and being lucky to get a capital A will take a lot of attempts, so i'll just set `letter = "A"` instead. I found the issue, will update the answer. You need to strip the newline from the file line.